# installing Angular Material in Visual Studio solution

Tags: angular, angular-material, visual-studio-2017

I have a large Visual Studio solution (running VS 2017) where some projects contain AngularJS (1.4.7) and some contain Angular (2.0). I don't think that's a problem, just making full disclosure.

I am currently trying to install Angular Material for use in the Angular project.

First question: are *material* and *material2* synonymous? I know there's a material for AngularJS, and I know there's a material for Angular, but they seem to use them interchangeably - or at least drop the version number occasionally. I go to install *material2* and I find myself installing *material*. I am hoping that it is just taking care of the correct versioning for me.

Using Powershell in my node_modules/@angular directory, I am running this:

**npm install --SAVE angular-material**

But this is what I get:

```
arv2@0.0.0 C:\proj\ClientPortal\dev\Leaves\MorneauShepell.ClientPortal\MorneauShepell.ClientPortal.Web
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular@>=1.3 <1.7
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-animate@>=1.3 <1.7
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-aria@>=1.3 <1.7
`-- angular-material@1.1.4

arv2@0.0.0 C:\proj\ClientPortal\dev\Leaves\myCo.ClientPortal\myCo.ClientPortal.Web
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular@>=1.3 <1.7
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-animate@>=1.3 <1.7
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-aria@>=1.3 <1.7
`-- angular-material@1.1.4

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any
"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN angular-material@1.1.4 requires a peer of angular@>=1.3 <1.7 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-material@1.1.4 requires a peer of angular-animate@>=1.3 <1.7 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-material@1.1.4 requires a peer of angular-aria@>=1.3 <1.7 but none was installed.
```

I'm afraid I don't know why it's complaining or what do about it.

Comment: (Mod edit: "Use angular 2.x instead".  That tag does not show up. It just defaults to angular anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are completely different libraries, each with their own syntax. You are installing the Material library for AngularJS with `angular-material` (For the record, Material for Angular 2+ is the package `@angular/material`). The Material library for Angular 2+ was originally called `material2`, but this name was revisioned and it's rarely referred to as `material2`, just Material. The repo for `@angular/material` is also still called `material2`.

Here, npm is telling you that you have some unmet dependencies. The [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started) for `angualr-material` (which I'll reference as AngularJS Material) state that you need to `npm install` `angular-animate` and `angular-aria`, which are normally supplemental libraries to `AngularJS` but are used by the Material library. You'll need to reference them in your HTML (or just use a CDN) and import them into your Angular module. You'll also need `angular-messages`, but it looks like you have that installed already.

> npm WARN angular-material@1.1.4 requires a peer of angular@>=1.3 <1.7 but none was installed.

That one doesn't really make sense, as you mentioned you have 1.4.7 installed. Sometimes NPM can be a bit inaccurate with its warnings, so I would ignore this unless your app experiences problems. Also, just a thought based on your filepaths...do you have `node_modules` in a static location or in multiple locations? If multiple, that could cause npm to mess up when it's searching for dependencies.